# Is there a better way for analysing the path between input/outuput arrays given as example?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

The example shown bellow is a simplified version of a signal path analysis that I am doing at the moment. For each index in the Input Array (*iArray*) there is an output (*oArray*) exactly at the same index. As you can see in the result, the recursive call will have duplicate analysis paths which are not important (*as indicated in the result*). The question is if there is any better (i.e. faster) solution for the analysis?

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {

    private static String[] iArray = new String[]{
        "a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c",
          "d","d","d","d","e","e","e","e","f","f","g","g","g","g",
            "h","h","k","l","l","m","n","n","n","n","n","o","o",
              "s","s","s","s","s","s"};

    private static String[] oArray = new String[]{
        "b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","d","f","h","l","j","a","n",
          "s","a","f","g","i","s","b","b","n","a","c","i","j","e","s",
            "b","b","o","d","s","a","b","b","s","a","j","l","o","n","k"};

    public static void recPathAnalysis(String signal, int level, String path) {
        if (level < 10) {
            for (int i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {
                if (signal.equals(iArray[i])) {
                    if (!path.contains(oArray[i])) {
                        System.out.println("normal >> " + path + " " + oArray[i]);              
                        recPathAnalysis(oArray[i], level + 1 ,  path + " " + oArray[i]);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("loop   >> " + path + " " + oArray[i]);              
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        recPathAnalysis("a", 0, "a");
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
    normal >> a b            **not needed**
    normal >> a b e          **not needed**
    loop   >> a b e a
    normal >> a b e f        **not needed**
    normal >> a b e f s      **not needed** 
    loop   >> a b e f s a
    normal >> a b e f s j
    normal >> a b e f s l    **not needed**
    loop   >> a b e f s l s
    loop   >> a b e f s l b
    normal >> a b e f s o    **not needed**
    loop   >> a b e f s o b
    loop   >> a b e f s o s
    normal >> a b e f s n    **not needed**
    normal >> a b e f s n o
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement that can be done in the data structure used here is that, instead of `public static void recPathAnalysis(String signal, int level, String path)`,  `public static void recPathAnalysis(String signal, int level, HashSet<Character> path)` can be used. Since you use `if (!path.contains(oArray[i]))` the complexity is O(n) but if you the same with HashSet it is O(1). A slight performance gain can be achieved.

Comment: For the  improvement that would help a lot since there are 6531 input and respectively output signals. :)

Comment: This is partly the answer (which is only related to finding the loop). More importantly is the duplicate recursions. ;)

Comment: Common approaches for this type of problems are Backtracking (DFS) and BFS. You have used backtracking here .Since you need any path of a particular length (assumed from your question) I think the solution you used is itself good other than data structure you used for which I suggested an alternative :-). So I cant give a better solution than yours, except dont print each and every statement since it may use processor cycles :-)

Comment: One more improvement that can be done is that, you can pass the array's index as parameter that can used inside the loop as the start value. I answered this in assumption that the iArray is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what your algorithm is about, but my general advice is to not print when you make the recursive call.

instead you could try to work around like this:

```
    if (level < 10) {
        for (int i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {
            if (signal.equals(iArray[i])) {
                if (!path.contains(oArray[i])) {            
                    recPathAnalysis(oArray[i], level + 1 ,  path + " " + oArray[i]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("loop   >> " + path + " " + oArray[i]);              
                }
            } else { // stop condition
                System.out.println("normal >> " + path + " " + oArray[i - 1]);
            }
        }
    } else { // stop condition
      System.out.println("normal >> " + path + " " + oArray[i - 1]);
    }
```

And do the same for the other stopping conditions.

Comment: The level is just to make sure the analysis does not go further more than that. For this example you can remove the level check.